# adding key to a ruby hash i'm creating

Tags: ruby, hash

So I've decided to improve my Ruby while signed off work with ophthalmic shingles.

I've written this script to get forecast data from the MetOffice's Datapoint API.

The bit i'm stuck at is

```
#!/bin/ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

#
# This script get the list of UK forecast locations
#
require 'pp'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'uri'

@apikey = 'insert-key-here'
@base_url = 'http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/'
@format = 'json'

# Make API call to get list of UK locations

def sitelist_data
  res = "val/wxfcs/all/#{@format}/sitelist?"
  url = "#{@base_url}#{res}key=#{@apikey}"
  url = URI.parse(url)
  resp = Net::HTTP.get(url)
  data = ::JSON.parse(resp)
  data['Locations']['Location'] # Step into the array to get location list
end

# All i need from the list is Authority name and Site name
# Create a list to display all available locations
def sitelist
  @fulllist = sitelist_data
  region_list = {}
  @fulllist.map do |k, _v|
    k.each do |key, value|
      @auth = value if key == 'unitaryAuthArea'
      @name = value if key == 'name'
    end
    region_list[@auth] = @name
  end
  region_list # Return list of locations
end

# Get a 3 hrly forecast for the next 5 days for the chosen location

# Get the raw 3hrly data for a specific region 
def three_hourly_forecast_raw(region)
  res = 'val/wxfcs/all/'
  reg = region
  url = "#{@base_url}#{res}#{@format}/#{reg}?res=3hourly&key=#{@apikey}"
  url = URI.parse(url)
  resp = Net::HTTP.get(url)
  data = ::JSON.parse(resp)
  data['SiteRep']['DV']['Location'] # Step into array to get to forecasts data
end

# Get the headders from the data id, name, longitude and latittude
def three_hourly_forecast_headder(region)
  raw_data = three_hourly_forecast_raw(region)
  raw_data.each do |key, value|
    @id = value if key == 'i'
    @reg = value if key == 'name'
    @lon = value if key == 'lon'
    @lat = value if key == 'lat'
  end
end

# Create a hash of the forecast data with new keys as
# the ones provided by met office are not great
def three_hourly_forecast_values(region)
  three_hourly_forecast = {}
  raw_data = three_hourly_forecast_raw(region)
  raw_data['Period'].map do |key, _value|
    @date = key['value']
    key['Rep'].map do |weather_data, _v|
      three_hourly_forecast[@date] = forecast_hash(weather_data)
    end
  end
end

# Compile weather data hash
def forecast_hash(weather_data)
  {
    hr: weather_data["\$"],
    feels_like: weather_data['F'], # unit = c
    w_gust: weather_data['G'], # unit = mph
    rel_humid: weather_data['H'], # unit = %
    temp: weather_data['T'], # unit = c
    visability: weather_data['V'],
    wind_dir: weather_data['D'], # unit = compass
    wind_speed: weather_data['S'], # unit = mph
    max_uv: weather_data['U'],
    type: weather_data['W'],
    percipitation_probability: weather_data['Pp'] # unit = %
  }
end

pp three_hourly_forecast_values('310069')
```

At the moment when I run the script, I get this

```
[{:hr=>"0",
   :feels_like=>"-1",
   :w_gust=>"40",
   :rel_humid=>"76",
   :temp=>"4",
   :visability=>"GO",
   :wind_dir=>"NW",
   :wind_speed=>"22",
   :max_uv=>"0",
   :type=>"7",
   :percipitation_probability=>"13"},
  {:hr=>"180",
   :feels_like=>"-1",
   :w_gust=>"40",
   :rel_humid=>"75",
   :temp=>"4",
   :visability=>"GO",
   :wind_dir=>"NW",
   :wind_speed=>"22",
   :max_uv=>"0",
   :type=>"2",
   :percipitation_probability=>"10"},
  {:hr=>"360",
   :feels_like=>"-1",
   :w_gust=>"40",
   :rel_humid=>"74",
   :temp=>"4",
   :visability=>"VG",
   :wind_dir=>"NW",
   :wind_speed=>"22",
   :max_uv=>"0",
   :type=>"2",
   :percipitation_probability=>"6"},
  {:hr=>"540",
   :feels_like=>"-1",
   :w_gust=>"36",
   :rel_humid=>"74",
   :temp=>"4",
   :visability=>"VG",
   :wind_dir=>"NNW",
   :wind_speed=>"20",
   :max_uv=>"1",
   :type=>"3",
   :percipitation_probability=>"4"},
  {:hr=>"720",
   :feels_like=>"1",
   :w_gust=>"40",
   :rel_humid=>"63",
   :temp=>"6",
   :visability=>"VG",
   :wind_dir=>"NNW",
   :wind_speed=>"22",
   :max_uv=>"1",
   :type=>"3",
   :percipitation_probability=>"3"},
  {:hr=>"900",
   :feels_like=>"1",
   :w_gust=>"34",
   :rel_humid=>"63",
   :temp=>"6",
   :visability=>"VG",
   :wind_dir=>"NW",
   :wind_speed=>"20",
   :max_uv=>"1",
   :type=>"3",
   :percipitation_probability=>"4"},
  {:hr=>"1080",
   :feels_like=>"0",
   :w_gust=>"27",
   :rel_humid=>"71",
   :temp=>"4",
   :visability=>"VG",
   :wind_dir=>"NW",
   :wind_speed=>"16",
   :max_uv=>"0",
   :type=>"0",
   :percipitation_probability=>"3"},
  {:hr=>"1260",
   :feels_like=>"-1",
   :w_gust=>"20",
   :rel_humid=>"77",
   :temp=>"3",
   :visability=>"VG",
   :wind_dir=>"NW",
   :wind_speed=>"13",
   :max_uv=>"0",
   :type=>"0",
   :percipitation_probability=>"3"}]
```

What i'd like is the date as the key to each hash, so it'd look like.

[ date => {
weather data
}

What am I doing wrong??

This is purely a learning project so it doesn't have to be uber-efficient​ or anything, but if you do spot anything that I could improve feel free to point it out.

Thanks

Comment: I think you have way too much unrelated code in your question, you should simplify it into the minimum required to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning three_hourly_forecast[@date] to forecast_hash(weather_data) inside a map function. The map function returns the last line, in that case it would be just the hash forecast_hash(weather_data). Change map to each to fix it.

```
 def three_hourly_forecast_values(region)
  three_hourly_forecast = {}
  raw_data = three_hourly_forecast_raw(region)
  raw_data['Period'].each do |key, _value|
    @date = key['value']
    key['Rep'].each do |weather_data, _v|
      three_hourly_forecast[@date] = forecast_hash(weather_data)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: By changing .map to .each it returns the original hash i.e. with the MetOffice keys and not mine.

Comment: return the three_hourly_forecast at the end.

Comment: Your right changing it to each and returning it at the end of the loop worked. Thanks.   `three_hourly_forecast = {}
  raw_data = three_hourly_forecast_raw(region)
  raw_data['Period'].map do |key, _value|
    @date = key['value']
    key['Rep'].each do |weather_data, _v|
      three_hourly_forecast[@date] = forecast_hash(weather_data)
    end
    three_hourly_forecast
  end
  three_hourly_forecast
end
```

Comment: Sorry about the bad comment above, fat fingers and a doggy eye dont go well together. You were right to change it to .each and return the hash at the end of the loop. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

The three_hourly_forecast_values method will return the result of the .map call and not your new hash that is built inside of the map block since it is the last object.  You can place the three_hourly_forecast hash as the last line in that method to return your new hash.

```
def three_hourly_forecast_values(region)
  three_hourly_forecast = {}
  raw_data = three_hourly_forecast_raw(region)
  raw_data['Period'].map do |key, _value|
    @date = key['value']
    three_hourly_forecast[@date] = []
    key['Rep'].map do |weather_data, _v|
      three_hourly_forecast[@date] << forecast_hash(weather_data)
    end
  end
  three_hourly_forecast
end
```

Comment: When i return the hash outside of the .map it adds the date as the key but the hash only contains the last hash entry. so i get [date => {last of 6 enrtries]. instead of [date => {entry 1}, {entry 2}, {entry 3}] Apologies if this doesn't make sense I'm struggling to type with one eye.

Comment: Do you have an example response for the three_hourly_forecast_raw method?  I do see that when three_hourly_forecast[@date] is set in a loop that each iteration would update the existing value of that hash key and not add to the key.  I can updated my answer with an example of this.

Comment: I've dumped a copy of the json output from three_hourly_forcast_raw method in my repo https://github.com/simon71/magic_mirror_ruby/blob/master/bin/raw_data_output.txt. Hope this helps and thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: The changes I made to my original code block above to create a new empty array assigned to the hash key and then adds each parsed weather_data to that key appears to get the format you are after.  I ran this using the data block you provided to validate.   Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you got your data into a variable called **data**

```
data = [{:hr=>"0",
         :feels_like=>"-1",
         :w_gust=>"40",
         :rel_humid=>"76",
         :temp=>"4",
         :visability=>"GO",
         :wind_dir=>"NW",
         :wind_speed=>"22",
         :max_uv=>"0",
         :type=>"7",
         :percipitation_probability=>"13"},
        ]

 data.each do |f|
   f.merge!(date: "Whether data")
  end
```

**Out put**

```
       [{:hr=>"0",
         :feels_like=>"-1",
         :w_gust=>"40",
         :rel_humid=>"76",
         :temp=>"4",
         :visability=>"GO",
         :wind_dir=>"NW",
         :wind_speed=>"22",
         :max_uv=>"0",
         :type=>"7",
         :percipitation_probability=>"13"},
         :date => "Whether data"
        ]
```

This will append **key**  and it's **value** to each hash.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the date is provided as a value in the original data. I want the date to be the key for each individual hash, not as a key-value pair within the hash. Thanks